Why when I use the Binding Navigator to Add new record, the ID file doesn't add the next number
I have a VB.net program linking to a SQL table, and I am using Binding Data. I set up and use the standard record navigation toolstrip, and I can move to and from records, but when I try to add a new record, it clears all the fields, but it won't automatically add the PK field to the next index number. In the table, I set the ID Column to- Identity true, the seed to 1 and the increment to 1, but no joy. The only way I can add a new number is manually, so the Identity needs to be false, but I want it to automatically add the next number, incrementing by 1.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong please. I didn't post the code as its the standard Toolstrip that I am using.

I haven't tested this but I suspect that the ID value won't be generated until the row is actually added to the DataTable, which doesn't happen at the point the row is created. That's because various fields in the row may be non-nullable. Try populating the other fields and then navigating away to a different record. At that point, the row will be added to the table and the ID should be generated. If you want to force it without navigating away, you need to call EndEdit on the BindingSource.

I tried filling every field, I also had a save button (in the Toolstrip) which has the code below, but it keeps crashing out with the error the ID Field (primary key cannot be null).     Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
'Me.Validate()
Me.StaffBindingSource.EndEdit()
Me.StaffTableAdapter.Update(Me.SimpleMaintenanceSystemDataSet.Staff)
End Sub

I just tested and a creating a new row via a BindingNavigator generated the ID value immediately for me. Either something is broken on your system or, more likely, you're doing something wrong, but it's hard to say what because your description is rather vague. Please read this and update your question accordingly. Note the word "minimal", which probably means creating a bare-bones test project, which you probably ought to have already done anyway. Isolating problem functionality is one of the first things to do.
